# Show that there exists $B>0$ so that $|f(x)|<B$ for all $x$, $0\leq x \leq 1$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is a function with the property that for every $a \in [0, 1]$ there is an open set $V_a$ containing $a$ and $B_a>0$ so that $|f(x)|<B_a$ for all $x\in V_a$. Show that there exists $B>0$ so that $|f(x)|<B$ for all $x$, $0\leq x \leq 1$.

I believe that this question has to do with compactness but I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Hint:  $\{V_a\}$ is an open cover of $[0,1],$ a compact set.

Comment: @UsernameUnknown The bells to which zhw is referring are specifically related to compactness. What is the definition of compactness you have, in a general topological space?

Comment: A subset K of a metric space $X$ is said to be compact if every open cover of $K$ contains a finite subcover. But how can you tell that $\{V_a\}$ has an finite subcover?

Comment: I don't know about continuous function yet

Answer (score 1):

Let $C=\cup_{0\leq a \leq 1} V_a$

$C $ is an open cover of  the compact $[0,1]$

thus $\exists \;\;$ finite set $F$ such that

$[0,1]\subset \cup_{a\in F}V_a$

let $B=\max_{a\in F}B_a$

we have

$\forall x\in[0,1] \;  |f(x)|<B$.

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like this but it seemed to obvious. What if we changed the last condition to $x\in(0,1]$? Does it not work because of the conditions of being an open cover?

Comment: Yes. The $V_a$ for $a$ near $0$ could be $]a/2,3a/2[$, and $B_a$ be $2/a$. Think of the function $f:x\mapsto\frac1x$.

Comment: So is it correct to say the following: Let $C=\cup_{0\leq a \leq 1} \hspace{0.25cm} V_a$. $C$ is an open cover of $(0,1]$. However $(0,1]$ is not a compact, since we can not find a finite subcover of it. i.e. there doesn't exists finite set $F$ such that $$(0,1]\subset \cup_{a\in F}V_a.$$ Hence $f$ is not necessarily bounded.